# Rigorous proof of one-dimensional Lie subgroup existence.

Tags: proof-explanation, lie-groups

[image]

So, that's an exert from Hochschild's "The structure of Lie Groups" p.79.
Existence and uniqueness of one-parametric Lie-Group embedding such that the given tangent vector of $G$ is the image of the unit canonical vector of R is being proved.

*I don't understand the first sentence of the proof.*

First of all, as far as I understand, $A$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$, $U$ a subset of $G$ containing $1$. There is kind of action over functions on $G$, that is constructed by a tangent vector.

What's the initial and target spaces of $\gamma_U$? How does $\gamma_U$ constructed? Why does the following condition can be satisfied?

Comment: First sentence: $\Bbb R^1$ is a Lie group. The axioms of a Lie group are obviously satisfied.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Could you elaborate this? Does the property mean that there is an analytical map between two Lie groups $\mathbb{R}$ and $G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hochschild is saying the following here:

Since $G$ is a real-analytic Lie group, we can identify (real-analytically) a neighborhood $A$ of $1\in G$ with an open subset $U\subset R^n$. Accordingly, the element $\gamma$ of the Lie algebra (regarded as a left-invariant real analytic vector field on $G$) becomes a real-analytic vector field on $U$, i.e. in the Cartesian coordinates $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ on $R^n$, the vector field $\gamma$ can be written as
$$
(p_1(x),...,p_n(x)),
$$
where each real-analytic function $p_i$ can be represented as a convergent power series on $U$. (For the latter, one may have to shrink the neighborhood $A$.) 
All he needs at this point is to quote the [Cauchy-Kovalevskaya theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Kowalevski_theorem) on differential equations with real-analytic coefficients. Maybe he does so on the next page...